# Make string starts with specified prefix in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to find out the native way to concatenate prefix to string, but only in case, it was not.

This code checks the `text` variable and makes it start with "#".

```
val text = "123456"
val prefix = "#"
val textFormatted = (if (text.startsWith(prefix)) "" else prefix ) + text
```

I hope there are clean solutions somewhere in Kotlin

Comment: `val textFormatted = if (text.startsWith(prefix)) text else prefix + text`

Comment: @k314159 In fact, I've already written an `ensureStartsWith()` (and `ensureEndsWith()`) function looking remarkably like that!

Comment: @gidds is it your extension function or Kotlin build-in one?

Comment: An extension: `fun CharSequence.ensureStartsWith(prefix: CharSequence) = if (startsWith(prefix)) toString() else "$prefix$this"` (and equivalent for `ensureEndsWith()`). (The `toString()` allows it to be used with any `CharSequence`; it's a no-op for `String`s.)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to use [removePrefix](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/remove-prefix.html):

```kotlin
val textFormatted = prefix + text.removePrefix(prefix)
```

Otherwise you could also keep the `if` but write it the following way to avoid extra parentheses and extra concatenation, and also make the code closer to the semantics:

```kotlin
val textFormatted = if (text.startsWith(prefix)) text else "$prefix$text"
```

But your solution works too.

Comment: Thanks! The 1st approach seems better, but before I was supposing we can avoid double "prefix" or "text" usage. I think it is impossible now, we have to write our own extensions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string interpolation from the kotlin, example:

```
val text:String = "123456#123456"
val prefix:String = "#"
val interpolation:String = "#${text.removePrefix(prefix)}"
```

Comment: what happens if the string is `#123#456#`? Also, why are you creating a val named `prefix` and then not using it?

Comment: Oh sorry, I will correct it. But usage interpolation is still valid.

Comment: the edit fixes all that I mentioned

Comment: No, it is not the way